# Spring Integration Deserializer not fetching the Entire Message through TCP

Tags: spring-integration

We are using the Spring Integration Flow to connect to the Tcp Port and fetch the Message.
Find Below the Code for the Same.

```
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundGateway(Tcp.nioServer(port)
                //.deserializer(new HL7Deserializer())
                .deserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader1())
               .serializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader1())
                ))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .channel("testChannel")
            .get();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testingChannnel() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("testChannel")
                .handle("messageHandler", "handleMessage")
            .get();
    }



@Component
public class MessageHandle implements MessageHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) {
        String payload = message.getPayload().toString();
        System.out.println("Received message: " + payload);
    }
}
```

**Input Message Given:**

MSH^~|&^HTAPPL^200TSQA~SQA-VENDOR~DNS^DG HOME TELEHEALTH^613~SQA-VA~DNS^20170530223011^^ACK~A04^200 TSQAApplication320170530223011^T^2.4^^^AL^NE^USA^
MSA^AA^613Application120170530223005^^^^0~Message accepted^

While Deserailizing not getting the whole message we are getting it part by part in payload.

**find below the deserailize message:**

Received message: MSH^~|&^HT
Received message: PPL^200TSQA~SQA-VENDOR~DNS^DG HOME TELEHEALTH^613~SQA-VA~DNS^2017
Received message: 530223011^^ACK~A04^200 TSQAApplication3201705302
Received message: 3011^T^2.4^^^AL^NE^USA^
MSA^AA^613Application12017

But we need to get it as a whole message what is the change required can you please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your flow doesn't look like request-reply: you start from the `Tcp.inboundGateway()`, but then you finish the flow with a `void` in your `MessageHandle`. This way you just don't produce any reply to fulfill the request-reply requirements. Look if that is really what you expect.

Then about the `.deserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader1())`: you need to be sure that TCP client on the other side does exactly opposite and serialize the message with same algorithm.

Comment: Have Added Message Handler to debug it. use case is like we need to listen to the Tcp Port and receive the message that is send to that port.   Have a message in the port but i am not fully getting that Message. One thing i noticed is MessagingMethodInvokerHelper is getting called four times and message is getting splitted according to that.

Comment: Right, but you need to agree a message demarcation strategy between server and client: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/ip/tcp-connection-factories.html#tcp-codecs

Comment: We have also used Custom Implementation for Deserialization but when the Socket is closed only we are receiving the message otherwise it is empty. How can we receive the message without closing the socket. is it possible ?

Comment: So, looks like the messages delimiter in your TCP/IP packages is not agreed between client and server. Why the standard `TcpCodecs.crlf()` or `TcpCodecs.lf()` is not enough for you?

Comment: can we be able to set the delimiter. Even we tried TcpCodecs.crlf() or TcpCodecs.lf()  but it is not getting any message. Even the handler itself is not getting called. We are using HL7 Simulator to send message to the Listening Port.  find below code                                           @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {

     return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundGateway(Tcp.netServer(port)
          .deserializer(TcpCodecs.lf())
             ))
           .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
          .channel("testChannel")
            .get();
    }

Comment: You need to consult with that  HL7 Simulator to determine what delimiter it uses for messages demarcation. According to its docs there is an `EOM` setting: https://www.hermetechnz.com/documentation/Ultraport/Listener/hl7_simulator.html